# Flask no encuentra el archvio CSS

Tags: html, python, css, flask

Estoy empezando a programar y tengo un problema con Flask, al ejecutarlo solo me carga el archivo HTML y no el CSS, estoy intentando hacer un login para luego ingresar a un panel de usuario el error es el siguiente:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 09:31:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> > 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 09:31:46] "GET /static/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
> >
> > > 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 09:31:46] "GET /static/css/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Este es el directorio de como tengo ubicado mi archivos en el escritorio en la carpeta "KDW"

```
 |-KDW/
 |---templates/
 |    |---static/
 |         |---css/
 |             |---img/
 |                  |---logo.png
 |                  |---fondo.png
 |             |---style.css
 |    |---index.html
 |---app.py(archivo que corre al inciar la aplicacion)
```

Este seria mi archivo app.py

```
from unicodedata import name
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL,MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = ''
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'app_kdexpress'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def home ():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

y este el HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KD EXPRESS</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css"*>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <h5>Inicia sesión</h5>
        <img src="static/css/img/logo.png" class="img-centro" alt="">
        <input class="controls" type="text" name="Usuario" value="" placeholder="User">
        <input class="controls" type="password" name="Usuario" value="" placeholder="Password">
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="" value="Ingresar">
        <p> </p>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Si ejecuto directamente el archivo index.html me abre el navegador con el login perfectamente con el estilo y todas las imágenes.

```
Intente cambiar 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css"*>
```

Por

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css' ) }}">
```

Y la consola sigue arrojando:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 10:42:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 10:42:09] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 10:42:09] "GET /static/css/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

```
[![Si ejecuto desde app.py][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OoU1.png
[![Si ejecuto directamente index.html][2]][2]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuW6B.jpg
```

Comment: Tenés una pista crucial en _GET /static/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404_ (énfasis en /static/static). Revisá tu `src` en `img`.

Comment: Para enlazar archivos externos se usa `url_for` donde debes colocarlo así `href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}">`

Comment: Cambie a <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}"> y sigue con este error:
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 10:23:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 10:23:29] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 10:23:29] "GET /static/css/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
Con la diferencia que ahora si entro a index.html directamente tampoco me carga el style.css

Comment: @padaleiana moví el archivo CSS a la carpeta static y me sigue dando error hora solo me sale un /static

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y ponlo _en la pregunta_. Como te habrás dado cuenta, es muy difícil leer código en los comentarios.

Comment: @padaleiana Disculpa, listo!

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste recargar la página? ¿Lo probaste en modo incógnito del navegador? (Para comprobar si hay datos _cacheados_)